# Correct usage of a command line in a process start in C#

Tags: c#, cmd, process, libreoffice

I have following problem:

I'm trying to convert odt files to pdf with libre office. When I use this cmd line this works great:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice.exe" 
--headless --convert-to pdf 
--outdir "C:\tmp" "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\File1.odt"
```

Now I tried to realize this with C#:

```
    private void ConvertOdtFileToPdf(string fileName)
    {
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            WorkingDirectory = ConfigManager.OutputPath,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            FileName = "soffice.exe",
            Arguments = $"--headless --convert-to pdf --outdir \"{Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)}\" \"{fileName}\""
        };
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

So here I want to convert a file which gets generated first into a pdf and save it to the same path. However this does not work. There happens absolutely nothing. I tried to change WorkingDirectory to the Directory of LibreOffice but still no effect. What is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you debug this piece of code and can you confirm that the input is a filename with its rooted path?

Comment: Yes. The file exists because it is getting generated before and it's filepath passed to the process. Could this have something to do with the WorkingDirectory or the escape characters?

Comment: It seems improbable if all of your arguments contains the correct full path Did you try to use just one dash for the options? (If the code runs on Window).

Comment: Yes this does not help. I debugged into it and all the filepaths seem to be correct. There are no spelling mistakes or something else. Is it rather possible to try this command directly programmatically over the cmd window?

Comment: Yes use cmd.exe for the file parameter and in the Arguments property add a /C and a space before the full command ...soffice.exe --headless..... Of course remove the WindowStyle hidden

Comment: If you want the console window open after the command then change /C with /K perhaps this will show if there is some error displayed in the output by the soffice.exe

Comment: Yes it tells me it could not find "C:\Program". But this is written in quotes.